# Illegal escape character error in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I've read [the manual](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html), and at the end there was an exercise:

> Use a backreference to write an expression that will match a person's name only if that person's first name and last name are the same.

I've written the next program http://pastebin.com/YkuUuP5M
But when I compile it, I'm getting an error:

```
PersonName.java:18: illegal escape character
p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\s+\1");
                                      ^
```

If I rewrite 18 line in this way:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));
```

and write the pattern in the console, then the program works fine. Why I can't use the pattern as in the 1st program case and is there some way to fix it?

Comment: \ in a string needs to be escaped. Use \\ . It becomes Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\\s+\\1");

Answer (score 7):

You want to get this text into a string:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\s+\1
```

However, `\` in a *string literal* in Java source code is the character used for escaping (e.g. "\t" for tab). Therefore you need to use "\" in a string literal to end up with a single backslash in the resulting string. So you want:

```
"([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\\s+\\1"
```

Note that there's nothing regular-expression-specific to this. *Any* time you want to express a string containing a backslash in a Java string literal, you'll need to escape that backslash. Regular expressions and Windows filenames are just the most common cases for that.

Comment: Java oh Java, when are you going to have verbatim strings?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ... if only - maybe in Java 10, 11, or 12? or do I remember reading somewhere that that's considered "syntactical candy" or something similar?

Comment: @CodeJockey Did you mean "[syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)"?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - YEAH! I knew it didn't sound quite right, but kinda close-ish (and I was too lazy to take the time to type it into Google)